# Removing MariaDB Installs MySQL and vice-versa

Tags: server, apt, mysql

A very stupid problem I'm facing on Ubuntu 16.04. I want to remove both MySQL and MariaDB client. If running `apt remove mysql-client*` I get this message:

```
The following additional packages will be installed:
  mariadb-client mariadb-client-10.0 mariadb-client-core-10.0 mariadb-common
The following packages will be REMOVED:
  mysql-client mysql-client-5.7 mysql-client-core-5.7
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  mariadb-client mariadb-client-10.0 mariadb-client-core-10.0 mariadb-common
```

And it removes MySQL but installs MariaDB instead. Then If I try to remove MariaDB, again MySQL will be installed automatically.

What the hell is this? How to get rid of both of them?

Comment: Why do you want to remove them? They are needed by another programme.

Comment: @spacelander MySQL stopped working after upgrading Ubuntu. I want to completely remove and re-install it.

Comment: did you try `apt remove mysql-client* mariadb*`?

Comment: Well are you proficient in MySQL? MariaDB is s fork of MySQL and thus (mostly) compatible

Comment: @spacelander MariaDB is not supporting JSON fields.

Comment: @dessert Nice! It's working

Comment: @Omid It is? I didn't really expect this to happen… Sometimes it's the simple things. ;-) Do you mind accepting my answer below?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to remove both:

```
sudo apt remove mysql-client* mariadb*
```

Comment: The most unexpected thing to happen ;) +1